# Getting exception: "Already in a write transaction" in Realm for Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin, realm

I'm using Realm in my Xamarin app, and I'm getting this exception in production. I have never seen it running the app myself, and it occurs only a few times daily. The complete stack trace is:

```
System.AggregateException', reason: 'System.AggregateException: 
A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. 
---> Realms.RealmInvalidTransactionException: The Realm is already in a write transaction at Realms.NativeException.ThrowIfNecessary (System.Func`2 overrider) <0xab3dfc + 0x00038> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Realms.SharedRealmHandle.BeginTransaction () <0xab21c8 + 0x00043> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Realms.Transaction..ctor (Realms.SharedRealmHandle sharedRealmHandle) <0xab9ad8 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Realms.Realm.BeginWrite () <0xab7624 + 0x0003f> in <filename unknown>:0 
at Realms.Realm.Write (System.Action action) <0xab7674 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0 
at MyApp.iOS.CollectionViewSource+<GetCell>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__2 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 value) <0x327c34 + 0x001b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1[TAntecedentResult].InnerInvoke () <0x532fa8 + 0x00077> in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x52ed88 + 0x0005b> in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm sure that my app only have one write transaction opened at once. The only thing that I think may be causing problems is that the realm transaction don't close properly. My code is something like this:

```
// this is called at some point in the app, when entering in a specific view controller
var transaction = realm.BeginWrite ();
```

The code for close this Controller is:

```
public void Close(bool saveChanges) {
    if (saveChanges) {
        transaction.Commit ();
        transaction.Dispose ();
    }       
    else {
        transaction.Rollback ();
        transaction.Dispose ();
    }

    // Ignore the fact that this code can be included in the previous section
    // It is just for making clear that after closing the transaction I can make 
    // a simple change to the objects
    if (saveChanges) {
        realm.Write(() => { 
            model.id = 1;
        }
    }

    NavigationController.PopToRootViewController (true);
}
```

When the root view controller is shown, then it accesses to the realm data and in this moment is when the crash occurred.

Any hint regarding to what can be happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first reaction was that the most likely thing is that your `Close` is not always being called. Is there any way your app can make a transition to another screen, or **re-enter** this one, without calling `Close`?

**However**

Looking at your stack trace, something that struck me is that you are apparently calling a `Write` from a cell getter, which is what is causing the crash:

`MyApp.iOS.CollectionViewSource+<GetCell...`

Do you have a list that is being refreshed whilst that screen is open?

**Update**

One thing to note from the comments below, that may be confusing you.

There are **two** ways to start a write transaction in Realm.

`BeginTransaction` creates and returns a transaction, so you have the chance to call `Rollback`.

The `Realm.Write( lambda )` call **also creates a temporary Write Transaction** so you cannot invoke it on the same thread.

I think this is a possible source of confusion and will discuss with the team if we should both update the docs and also try to improve the exception messages to pick up if a `Write` is being called in this situation.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your reply. You can find the app when this behavior occurs here (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instant-resume-cv-resume-builder/id1140528477?ls=1&mt=8). The only place in my code when I opened a transaction via realm.BeginWrite () is in the theme editor (Edit > Customize Current Theme). If you choose Cancel, the changes are rollbacked, and I you choose apply, the changes are saved and then you go to the Home screen, is in this screen that the crash occurs. Note that when you make a change, the cells load a progress indicator while performing the update task.

Comment: After the task finished is executed the code that modify the realm object, and is there when the crash occurs. After seeing you answer the only way that I can imagine the app may crash is when the update task takes too long to finish and the user go to the Theme Editor, since when I opened this View I call to realm.BeginWrite, if the task finished after that then the crash occurs. I hope this be the bug

Comment: Ok. I made a test and it seems that this is exactly the problem. Or at least I get the same error when try to reproduce these steps. Thanks!

Comment: Explained more about write transactions by editing my answer above.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you can also open a transaction using the lambda, that is why I wrote "The only place in my code when I opened a transaction VIA realm.BeginWrite ()". I just considered this as the problematic way since every time that I use the lambda expression is for saving a few properties, and all these changes are performed in the main thread, so, there is no way to have two lambda transactions opened at the same time.

Comment: @ReynaldoAguilar did you resolve this or is there still an problem?

Comment: @KristianDupont Well, the crash is still there. The only solution that I have found so far is to avoid the RollBack call

Comment: I see. We created an [issues](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/851) for this, but I am not sure how to debug it. Is it possible for you to create a test project that reproduces the problem? Or alternatively share your project with us (confidentially -- we'll sign an NDA if necessary)

Comment: @KristianDupont Hmmm, I think that I can't. Even in my own project the crash doesn't occurs too frequently, I have been able to reproduce it only in one device, and the crash occurs randomly. The only realm calls involved are the ones that occur when you call the above function with `false` as parameter.

Comment: @ReynaldoAguilar I see. Well in that case, please let us know if you discover any more hints at the problem and update the github issue. I will try and see if I can reproduce it somehow and keep an eye out for it.